# Unlock iPhone 5 help

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I have an iPhone 5 through Virgin Mobile USA. They say cannot unlock it due to "not having the technology", they say they can only unlock iPhone 5c and 5s. They did however give me the code which is useless because I don't know how to do it.

Is there a way to unlock it myself using the code? I tried going to a different carrier, but the iPhone gave the "SIM is invalid" error so I had to transfer my number back to Virgin Mobile after the other account was active.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Sprint will not do anything for me either.
Tried bringing it to some places no one could do it.

Comment: iPhones are (carrier) unlocked remotely by Apple on carrier request, at least in Chile. I've successfully unlocked an iPhone 4, 5 and 6 "Not having the technology" sounds like a weird and bogus answer to me, can you escalate your request on Virgin? Or visit another store / customer service?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I was on the phone for hours with Virgin got absolutely no where.At one point I was on a three way call with Apple and Virgin.Still got nowhere.It gets me mad because it is my phone paid in full and even though they say no contract I am stuck with them until I can get the phone unlocked.Maybe I will try again and get VM to get apple to unlock but Im sure it will be a waste of time.

Comment: I assume you're talking about carrier-unlocking your phone, so you can use it with another carrier. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Also, I don't know your contract,but  you may have to be with the carrier during the full length of your contract in order to own the device and be able to unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

The flowchart on unlocking an iPhone (no matter what model or what carrier) is here. If you're having problems with Customer Support with a specific carrier. List the exact words you used to request the unlock and consider getting them to explain exactly what the issue is.

Hold their feet politely to the fire if they are not supporting you as a customer. You will need to be responsible for being clear with them and listening to exactly what they say so they don't "snow" you with irrelevant information. Once you share with them the exact steps you are undertaking (linked below) they will have no where to hide except to admit if they will or will not unlock the device.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201328

Answer (score 0):

One method that has proven to be safe and effective for unlocking your iPhone 5 or 5s is Network Unlocking. Companies have IMEI codes as unique identifiers for their phones. There is a listing of each iPhone’s model number, memory size, color, and production date. This list also tells whether the iPhone is locked to a certain network or not.
An IMEI Network Unlock will get your iPhone’s IMEI lock status changed so that it is unlocked. This means that you won’t have to have some unauthorized person bothering the hardware and wiring in your phone. There is also no software download needed. https://macback.us/tutorials/how-to-unlock-iphone-5-5s/